# How to disable HP printer push notifications on my computer?

Tags: printer, hp-photosmart

I have an HP C4385 Photosmart printer on my home network. I also have HP Solution Center and the relevant HP printer drivers installed on my computer.

Whenever certain events happen on the printer (e.g. out of paper, cartridge alignment, cover open), a push notification appears on my computer. It looks something like this:

[image: HP Photosmart C4380 series / Cover Open / Click here for more information]

Is there a way to disable these notifications?

**Edit:** I tried following the instructions here: https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c01841764

But when I went to the Device Settings for my printer, it just looks like this, and I can't find the settings for printer status notifications:

[image: Device Settings > HP Photosmart C4380 series Device Settings > Installable Options]

Also, I don't have seem to have any **HP UPD** item in my Devices and Printers page...

[image: Devices and Printers]

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @John only applies to printers that support the SNMP protocol. That only exists on network-connected printers.

It may be possible to achieve what you want. Check through the installed software and see what kind of utilities are installed. There probably is some installed package like HP Solution Centre . In that case, you may be able to achieve it, by doing something like [these instructions](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printers-Archive-Read-Only/How-to-turn-off-ink-notifications/td-p/3716530) for the "HP Utility" for a different printer model.

HP really should do something about their bloatware. Your problem is caused by the fact that for your printer (and many of their low-cost printers) the only available driver is the "[Full Feature Software and Driver](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-Photosmart-C4300-All-in-One-Printer-series/3221640/model/3221645)". I have looked for a "printer-only" driver, which would avoid this problem, but have not been able to find one. And scanning could then be done with a simple TWAIN driver - if HP supplied one.

Answer (score 1):

That is common to HP Printer and I suggest you follow this HP article for disabling the notifications

https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c01841764

Relevant Quote from the article above:

> Enabling or disabling SNP requires the following items:
>
> Printer Automatic Configuration is enabled and functional. Printer Automatic Configuration can be disabled in HP UPD version v4.7 or later with a print policy with HP UPD or Active Directory Group Policy. See and Manage the HP UPD with Active Directory Group Policy for more information. SNP can also be disabled using the HP Driver Configuration Utility prior to installation. See Manage the SNP with the HP Driver Configuration Utility.
>
> The product supports SNP functionality
>
> The product is not a PCL3 product
>
> Follow these steps to enable or disable SNP from the Device Settings tab:
>
> - Open the Devices and Printers folder, right-click the HP UPD, and then select Properties.
> - Click the Device Settings tab.
> - In the Installable Options section, set Printer Status Notification to either Enable or Disable.
> - Click OK.

Comment: Please provide all relevant information in the answer body necessary to answer the authors question.  HP is notorious for breaking links and not redirecting to the new location.

Comment: While you provided the relevant info, as original posted it was unreadable and your “quoting” was basically to simply say the words “quote” and “unquote.” You seem to be enthusiastic about being a part of this community, so please [read up on how posts should be formatted for readability and usability](https://superuser.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same annoying issue with HP Laserjet 107a, this is what I did.

1. open Control Panel - Devices and Printers
2. select HP Laserjet 107a and right-click Printing preferences
3. look for and click Printer Status
4. click Option
5. uncheck Display printing status message when printing is in progress

Answer (score -2):

Disable annoying HP printer ads on Window 10

Type devices and printers in Cortana search box

Click on it and chose details view

Left click on your HP printer

window should come up.

Left click on customize your printer

Click on Ports tab and uncheck Enable bidirectional support
Then ok

**don’t think you have to restart computer